# Pathping for test Pinging from subnets

Tags: nmap, automated-testing

Does anyone know if PathPing or NMAP can ping or scan from predefinded source IPs?
I am checking connectivity from agents on remote hosts to a destination site from my host.
Is there a switch or tool to force a network test via a predefined source route?
I have a list of systems I need to pathping or nmap from.
Doing this from my host command shell would save a huge amount of time.
I am pretty sure the routers all have source routing disabled, but need help.

Thank you in advance.

Gregg

Comment: You can pivot from ports on your different subnets. It's not a tool but a technique.

Comment: Thank you Schroeder. I don't have access to the networking equipment, I'm just a host with a shell. I guess there is no way. It's in the DNA of TCPIP. We will see if anyone else cooments. **Otherwise** we close this as answered.  _italic_ Thanks again!

Comment: you don't need access to the networking equipment, just a host on the remote subnet

Comment: I have the IPs of hosts on each subnet, but I need to avoid any use of them except standard IP stack services on those hosts. :) Thank you,